# Linux fails to boot on VirtualBox with 2 CPUs

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I made a Linux Ubuntu 16.04 VDI image on VirtualBox on an Intel i7 machine (4 CPUs), with a set of tools inside. Then I copied that VDI to an old machine (Core 2 duo - 2 CPUs), I created the VM using the VDI file copy. The image boots, but runs very slowly with 1 CPU (which is obvious).

The problem now is that when I use all the 2 cores (in the older machine) the virtual machine doesn't boot, it displays the GRUB page, then a black screen (with a blinking cursor **_** ). Yet, the boot succeeds in the i7 machine with any number of cores (1-4). Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Is VT-X enabled on the old machine? [Is it even supported?](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005486/processors.html) (likely disabled by default even if supported). Running with one processor is slow but bearable, running without VT-X limits you to one processor and is much slower.

Comment: Yes it is enabled. The awkward thing is that I had an old image which was booting fine on 2 CPUs on the old machine. But for this image this is not the case :(

Comment: Was the old image perhaps a 32 bits version of Linux?